# Pivot table for Mongoose Schema ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pivot, schema

I have the following List schema:

```
const ListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    items: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Item'
    }],
});
```

Everything works fine when I populate it with items. However, I want to have an additional column for each item in the list so I changed the schema:

```
const ListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    items: [{
      item: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
      },
      quantity: 'String'
    }],
});
```

The populate method doesn't work with the above approach, unfortunately.

For a relational database I'd use a pivot table to save list id, item id and quantity but I really don't know how MongoDB treats such cases. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You should keep that `quantity` field inside the `items` collection.

Comment: No I am saying that you should keep it inside the `items` collection not with array of objects as you did here `items: [{
      item: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
      },
      quantity: 'String'
    }]`

Comment: Even if I add it like this `items: [{
    item: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item', quantity: 'String'
    },
  }],` it still doesn't add the quantity value to the database

Comment: Could you show your `items` collection

Comment: `const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, min: 1 },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190893/discussion-between-shakur-and-anthony-winzlet).

Comment: Ok so put that field here `const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: { type: String, required: true, min: 1 }, created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, quantity: String })`

Comment: It doesn't work. What's the point in adding quantity column to item schema? When I keep quantity outside the items collection I get what I need i.e. both id and quantity saved but I'm unable to populate the item's informations AND quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
const ListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
  items: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Item', quantity: 'String'
  }],
});
```

Basically I've changed the item's schema type from `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` to `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`.

This way when you `.populate('items._id')` you'll get everything from items document AND your additional column (quantity)